# Why is my car detection on satellite images so bad

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, object-detection

I am using SIMD dataset and I am trying to classify 15 types of vehicles on image.
My algo

1. Extract vehicles images from satellite images (we have annotations to do that)
2. Train test split 80/20
3. Train network (slightly edited from one tutorial)

   ```
   INIT_LR = 1e-4
   EPOCHS = 5
   BS = 32
   # load the MobileNetV2 network, ensuring the head FC layer sets are
   # left off
   baseModel = MobileNetV2(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
       input_tensor=Input(shape=(416, 416, 3)))

   # construct the head of the model that will be placed on top of the
   # the base model
   headModel = baseModel.output
   headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7))(headModel)
   headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
   headModel = Dense(128, activation="relu")(headModel)
   headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
   headModel = Dense(15, activation="softmax")(headModel)

   # place the head FC model on top of the base model (this will become
   # the actual model we will train)
   model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

   # loop over all layers in the base model and freeze them so they will
   # *not* be updated during the first training process
   for layer in baseModel.layers:
       layer.trainable = False

   # compile our model
   print("[INFO] compiling model...")
   opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR)
   model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
   metrics=["accuracy"])

   # train the head of the network
   print("[INFO] training head...")
   H = model.fit(
   trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS,
   steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
   validation_data=(testX, testY),
   validation_steps=len(testX) // BS,
   epochs=EPOCHS)
   ```
4. Selective search on image
5. Predict
   And this is the result
   [Predicted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FcMs.jpg)
   Results are worse than bad but it's even on train image. Cars have very low certainty around 20% while many objects around have higher.  I don't know what to start editing somehow every network training took forever. I want to ask for any hints on where to start network accuracy shows around 77% during training. Will be helpful to set epochs to a higher number like 50 ? Or is it a more network structure-related problem? And yes it's my first network.

Comment: According to your code, you used 5 epochs, is that right? You could try more. Furthermore you could try to reduce the dropout. From 0.5 to 0.2. From looking at it I would say that the problem is that your model/net is not tuned enough. Maybe you have to also play around a bit more with the structure.

Comment: @PSt thank you for the feedback I am going to try it. :)